# Proof of $\int_{a}^{a} f(x)dx = 0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

For this proof, after I convert the definite integral into the riemann sum definition, is it just enough to say $\Delta(x)$ = $\frac{b-a}{n}$ and since b = a, the $\Delta(x)$ becomes 0, thus, making everything else equal to 0, since everything else is being multiplied by zero?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: As you note, the Riemann sum becomes $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i^\ast) \Delta x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(a) \cdot 0 = 0, $$ where $x_i^{\ast}$ is some marking of the partition.  Looks good to me.

Comment: In the Riemann sum, it's not necessarily $\Delta(x)$ that becomes $0$, it can also be $n$ (the number of terms in the sum). You choose as you write the proof.

Comment: but the delta x becomes zero because b is equal to a and a-a is 0, so wouldn't that make everything else equal to zero?

Comment: @Arthur Then $\Delta(x)=?$  I checked Rudin's PMA: Riemann sum is defined on an interval $[a,b]$, whose definition (2.17) allows $a\le x\le b$, so it's right to say $\Delta(x) = 0$

Comment: $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$  b = a, thus $\Delta x = \frac{0}{n}$ so wouldn't that make everything equal to zero?

Comment: @Arthur The integral is defined as $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x := \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i^{\ast}) \Delta x, $$ where $\{x_i^{\ast}\}$ is some marking of the partition of uniform intervals of length $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$, assuming that the limit exists (more or less).  Here, we are integrating over the degenerate interval $[a,a]$, so $\Delta x = 0$.

Comment: So then that would make everything else equal to zero then right? cuz its being multiplied by zero

Comment: @XanderHenderson But are there any partitions of $[a,a]$? Probably depends on the the precise definition... I could see there either being one with length $0$ or being none. FWIW the definition on the wikipedia article for RI seems like it implies there are none, but don't another source like Rudin in from of me.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Hmm, I might have been a bit quick there... It made sense in my head before I read your responses, but now I'm uncertain. The idea is that you can have an empty partition.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I suppose that depends on exactly how a partition is defined.  If you define a partition by the points $\{ x_i = a + i\Delta x\}$, then there is a fairly trivial partition of a degenerate interval.  Alternatively, the *only* partition of $[a,a]$ is the partition $\{a= a\}$, from which we may still obtain that the integral is zero.

Comment: I'm kinda confused now

Comment: Wouldn't the partition just be from a to a? meaning from a to itself?

Comment: @dg123 It depends on what, exactly, your definition of a partition is, and how rigorous the text you are using is.  Some texts are fairly loosey-goosey and say "Divide the interval into equal pieces and pick a point in each subinterval.  Take the number of pieces to infinity."  If this is your definition, then you are adding up an infinite number of zeroes.  More rigorously, with a marked partition $\{a = x_0^{\ast} < x_1^{\ast} < \dotsb < x_n^{\ast} = b\}$ (not necessarily uniform, but of bounded mesh size), sum we write (continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i^{\ast}) \Delta x_i, $$ where $\Delta x_i$ is the width of the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$.  In this setting, only one partition is possible, the sum is zero for this partition, and so the result follows by some kind of vacuity.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I think I wasn't thinking quite right about the wikipedia definition. I was forgetting the case of an empty sequence of $x$'s, which implies that the one-element $\{[a,b]\}$ is a partition for any interval, including degenerate ones, which seems morally correct.

Comment: I think that was the definition I was looking for where the interval is [$x_{i-1}, x_{i}$]

Answer (score 3):

We can use also  the empty sum definition
$$\sum^0_{k=1} f(k)=0 $$ for every f.

One partition is in the form
$a=t_0<t_1< \ldots <t_n=b$
if $a=b$ then $n=0$.

Let it be the degenerate interval $[a,a]=\{a\}$, we have $t_{0}=a$ and $t_{n}=a$, we should have   $t_{1}>t_{0}=a$ but we don't have one number greater then $a$ in the interval. We have only one partition. The inferior summation is
 $$s(f,P)=\sum^{n=0}_{k=1}m_{k}\Delta t_{k-1}=0 $$
 because it's empty.
 The superior summation is
 $$S(f,P)=\sum^{n=0}_{k=1}M_{k}\Delta t_{k-1}=0 $$
In this case the inferior summation is always equal the superior summation
and the same for the superior and inferior integrals. So every function will be integrable in this set and the integral $0$
 $$\int^{a}_{a} f(x)dx=0. $$

Comment: What about the riemann definition? Would what I said be enough to prove it?

Comment: @dg123 This is the definition of the Riemann integral...

Comment: Shouldn't there by the limit sign?

Comment: @dg123 Limit of a constant sequence is the constant itself.  Btw, you can use empty sum, but if you adopt Baby Rudin's definition for Riemann integrals and intervals, there's no need to introduce empty sum because $[a,a]$ *is* an interval itself, and a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ is a ordered finite set of points starting from $a$ and ending at $b$.
$$a = x_0 \le x_1 \le \cdots \le x_n = b$$
Therefore, it's ok to let the partition $P$ to be $a \le a \le \cdots \le a$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick with this?

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^a f(x)\, dx &= F(x)\bigr|_a^a \\
&= F(a)-F(a) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

where $F’(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: @qbert How is the inconclusiveness a result of using antiderivatives and not just due to the specific choice of $f(x)$ and $a$?

Comment: For differentiability, we usually assume functions are defined on an open set. A function $f:[a,a] \to \mathbb{R}$ is thus not differentiable at $a$ (or, for that matter, antidifferentiable). Look at the hypotheses of the fundamental theorem of calculus more carefully.

Comment: @dg123 [the first fundamental theorem of calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html)

Comment: I haven't learned that yet

Comment: @dg123 Ah, that’s too bad ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It will soon become a best friend. Can I ask what your scholastic situation is?